# SSH средствами PHP. Проблема с stream_get_contents() при работе с CLI Python

Tags: python, php, linux, apache, ssh

Реализовываю работу с SSH средствами PHP. Задача присоединиться к удаленной машине и выполнить на ней некий код на Python через его интерфейс командной строки. Версия библиотеки ssh2 1.2. Вот немного кода для наглядности:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($this->rpihost, $this->rpiport);

if ($connection) {
   echo ...
} else {
   echo ...
   die();
}

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->rpiuserame, $this->rpipassword)) {
   echo ...
} else {
   echo ...
   die();
}

// echo $this->execute($connection, 'python3 --version');
echo $this->execute($connection, 'python3');

ssh2_disconnect($connection);
```

В родительском классе есть следующий метод:

```
protected function execute($connection, $command)
{
    $stdout_stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);

    $sio_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    $err_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
    
    stream_set_blocking($sio_stream, true);
    stream_set_blocking($err_stream, true);
        

    $result_dio = stream_get_contents($sio_stream);
    $result_err = stream_get_contents($err_stream);

    if (empty($result_err)) {
        return $result_dio;
    } else {
        return $result_err;
    }
        
}
```

Простые команды, которые просто выводят какой-то результат, выполняются успешно. Наример, `$this->execute($connection, 'python3 --version');` возвращает в моем случае "Python 3.8.10" и т.д.

Если же я пытаюсь открыть интерфейс командной строки подобным образом `$this->execute($connection, 'python3');` и второй аргумент [stream_set_blocking()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-set-blocking.php) является true, т.е. установлен блокирующий режим потока, то при выполнении [stream_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-get-contents.php) имеет место, насколько я понимаю по логам, быть зацикливание и заканчивается память. Приходится делать серверу перезагрузку. Вот сами логи, точнее их фрагмент:

```
[Tue Oct 18 20:00:26.022985 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3272:tid 140211077998336] [client ***:60832] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header, referer: https://***.php
[Tue Oct 18 20:00:26.023024 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3272:tid 140211077998336] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client ***:60832] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://***.php
```

Насколько я понимаю, CLI Python-а не дает поток, а [stream_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-get-contents.php) перманентно пытается его считать, отсюда out of memory error.

Пытался вот так:

```
if (!empty($stdout_stream)) {
...
```

...но ничего не получается. Как исправить?

Comment: Так питон или пхп?